# Can I install Wubi on Windows 10?

Tags: wubi, windows-10

I have installed Windows 10 and now I want to install Wubi... Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

From [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide):

> Wubi is an officially supported installer for Windows XP, Vista and 7
>   only. Wubi does not work with Windows 8 default boot-loader.
>   Thus at this point Wubi would not work on a new Windows 8 machine. You
>   would be able to install, but not reboot into Ubuntu.
>
> If you upgraded to Windows 8 and are using BIOS firmware, Wubi does
>   work, but do not enable hybrid-sleep on Windows 8

Note that this applies to Windows 10 also.

Comment: @tamale I have to disagree. Wubi is still *officially* not supported. Thanks for pointing out the repo though. It wasn't there at the time of this post I guess.

Answer (score 5):

In fact WUBI works with Windows 10. I had Ubuntu installed with WUBI to Windows 7. When I upgraded to Windows 10 I left it there, and it still works fine (Ubuntu 13.10).

I have not tried installing WUBI directlly on Windows 10, though.

Comment: I tried it on a preinstalled Windows 10. It worked similar to my experience on a preinstalled Windows 8.1 see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/737547/386067).  It is definitively possible, also if you have preinstalled system with UEFI. On my experience the [commnunity supported versions](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases) work for beginners, too and [the official Wubi version for 14.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/wubi.exe) works for developers only.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is a project in the works to allow you to use wubi with uefi bios PCs and I just used it on a brand new HP spectre x360 with windows 10 home to install ubuntu 16.10.  It worked perfectly after I disabled secure boot in BIOS.

https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/releases

Comment: Even if it works, this method is not officially supported.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Wubi does not support either Windows 8 or Windows 10.

You can install Ubuntu as dual boot with Windows 10 the same way as with Windows 8.

[This is the guide for it](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/167850).

Comment: There is wubiuefi for windows 10.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ## wubiuefi
>
> Wubi is the Windows Ubuntu Installer. Wubi installs Ubuntu inside a file
>   within a windows partition, and thus it does not require CD burning or
>   dedicated partitions, yet the installation is a dual boot setup identical
>   to a normal installation.

For more information see: https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki

---

From https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi

> ## Compiling
>
> - `make`: builds `wubi.exe`, note that the first time you run it, you
>     will have to install python inside of wine, this is performed
>     automatically, just confirm all the default choices in the
>     installation screens that will appear.
> - `make runpy`: runs wubi under wine directly from source
> - `make runbin`: builds wubi and runs the packaged binary under wine
> - `make wubizip`: creates a special zip file conatining python.exe
>     and non byte compiled python files that is convenient for debugging
>     purposes. Inside of Windows, unzip the archive, then run
>     `python.exe main.py --verbose`. You can edit any file inside of ./lib.
> - `make pot`: generates a gettext template (`po/wubi.pot`)
> - `make check_wine`: creates the Wine environment if it doesn't
>     exist.
> - `make check_winboot`: creates the environment for building and
>     signing boot loaders if it doesn't exist.
> - `make winboot`: creates the boot loader files (old version)
> - `make winboot2`: creates the boot loader files (new version)
> - `make clean`: removes built files
> - `make distclean`: removes built files and environment
>
> ## Code overview
>
> - `src/winui`: thin ctypes wrapper around win32 native graphical user
>     interface
> - `src/pylauncher`: makes python code into an executable, the python
>     script is examined and all the dependencies are added to an lzma
>     archive, then an executable header is concatenated to the archive that
>     decompresses it and runs the script using the python dll
> - `src/wubi`: the main wubi application, the code is split between
>     backend and frontend, where each runs in its own thread. The two
>     interact via a tasklist object, where the frontend usually runs a
>     tasklist which is a set of backend tasks. Backends and frontends are
>     platform specific. For now only the Windows platform is supported.
> - `data`: settings for wubi branding and customization
> - `po`: translations
> - `bin`: other binary files required at runtime (will be compiled at
>     a later stage)
>
> ## Wubi tasks
>
> Wubi performs the following tasks
>
> - fetches information about the running system which will be used
>     during installation
> - checks that the minimum installation requirements are met
> - retrieves required user information via a GUI
> - looks for available local CDs and ISO files
> - downloads the ISO if one is required, using bittorrent and an http
>     download manager
> - checks the ISO/CD md5 sums and the md5 signature
> - extracts the kernel and initrd from the ISO
> - adds a new boot entry to the existing windows bootloader
> - prepares a preseed file to be used during the linux-side
>     installation
> - allocates space for the virtual disk files
>
> *The actual installation is performed within linux after rebooting the machine.*
>
> ## Customizations
>
> - edit the files in data as appropriate and build your image
> - you will need to provide an ISO that is similar to the Ubuntu ISO
>     and in particular it must have .disk/info formatted like .disk/info in
>     the Ubuntu ISO
> - you must provide a webserver with metalink file, metalink file md5
>     checksums and signatures for the md5 sums
> - add your signing key to `data/trustedkeys.gpg`
> - replace the generated dummy keys in `.key` with your signing keys
>     for Secure Boot
> - on the linux side, the distribution must be capable of booting and
>     rebooting off a loop file, perform an automatic installation and
>     accept the special boot parameters that indicate the local preseed
>     file and ISO image to boot from.

[Here](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi) is the branch git clone, or download it compressed.

Comment: Most of this answer has been copy and pasted without using blockquote formating, nor explicitly stating the source (although the link is provided at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Wubi installed on Windows 7 then yes. You can upgrade Windows 7 to 10 and you still gonna have Ubuntu on your computer.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP has installed Windows 10 and is not asking about an upgrade to Windows 10.