# Installing wubi on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, wubi

can anyone guide me how to install wubi on W8.1. I have heard that there is a UEFI related issue on W8.1.

Comment: WUBI is not maintained or recomended. Either try a virtual machine or a real install.

Comment: Avoid Wubi or try a community supported version from [here](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki).

Comment: To the people voting to close the question: It's important to **keep it**, so other users can know Wubi's not supported. Please keep it open.

Comment: @Eduardo Cola I agree with you that this question should not be closed. I am currently working with a Wubi installed Lubuntu 15.10.  I use Wubi on a preinstalled Windows 8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 2):

Last hour, I installed Lubuntu 14.04.4 with Wubi on a preinstalled Windows 8.1 for a friend. It worked without problems. These were the neccessary steps for me, which could be also a guide for you.

- Download

I downloaded [lubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.4/release/lubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso) from [official release site](http://releases.ubuntu.com) and [wubi14044r302.exe](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/releases/download/14044r302/wubi14044r302.exe) from the [community supported Wubi site](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi)

- Run Wubi

I ran wubi14044r302.exe from my Windows download folder. In the same folder was the downloaded iso. I chose Lubuntu, user name and password and because there was only one Windows drive, I selected "C:"

- Installation

I pressed button "Install" and because I downloaded iso manually, no further download was needed and only few minutes later, I rebooted the system.

- UEFI firmware

I pressed the function key I read in the online manual of the notebook. Then I saw a menu entry with "Windows Boot Manager" and "Lubuntu". I selected "Lubuntu".

- Secure Boot

I saw an error message "access denied" but I could perform MokManager and imported the MOK key. After that I selected "continue" but it booted into Windows. After a second reboot I selected again "Lubuntu" and now the installation was completed.

- Completing installation

No further issues, I just waited about 10 minutes until a third reboot. I selected again "Lubuntu" and now I saw the freshly installed system.